# What is the name (if any) of this statistical analysis concept?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I have a list of random numbers.  I sort them, and designate each one as belonging to a tier of some sort (quartiles, percentiles, or even arbitrary cutoff points by proportion) based on the cumulative sum of them in that order.  What is this kind of analysis called?

This is *not* ordinary rank, as I don't care about how many there are in each group nor what their *numerical* position in the sorted list is.

Example:

Let's say I define four buckets:  A = top 16%, B = next 23%, C = next 28%, and D = the rest (33%).  I take 20 random numbers from 0 to 100, sort them, and slot them into these buckets according to the running total of them:

```
Value   Cumulative total    Bucket     Notes
   89                 89    A
   84                173    A          173 > 1014 * 16% = 162.24 ; next bucket
   76                249    B
   74                323    B
   65                388    B
   64                452    B          452 > 1014 * (16 + 23)% = 395.46 ; next bucket
   63                515    C
   57                572    C
   56                628    C
   54                682    C          682 > 1014 * (16 + 23 + 28)% = 679.38 ; next bucket
   54                736    D
   47                783    D
   47                830    D
   45                875    D
   45                920    D
   41                961    D
   26                987    D
   13               1000    D
    7               1007    D
    7               1014    D
```

Comment: Sort of binning where you've defined your own custom cutoffs for each bin.  If you were interested in bucket totals or bucket counts you could make histograms of those to visualize their distribution.  You've also converted an ordinal value to nominal which has use in various modeling strategies.  But what are YOU doing with this approach and why?

Comment: It's not my approach; it's part of a spec I'm working from.  But I'm wondering if this is any kind of standardized, known system.